# wp_verify_nonce return false despite correct parameter passed

Tags: nonce

I have created a form that have nonce

```
<form action="<?php echo get_rest_url(null, 'ilms_plugin/new_membership') ?>" method="post" class=' space-y-2 mt-2  p-2 rounded-md '>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new_membership','test_nonce' ); ?>
        <h1 class="pt-2 text-xl">New membership</h1> 
        <div class='pr-2'>Membership name</div><input name="membership_name" type="text" id='shortname' class="w-full"/>
        <div class='pr-2'>Description</div><textarea name="description" id="" cols="30" rows="6" class="w-full"></textarea>
        <div class="pr-2">Availability</div> Day <input name="membership_period_day" type="number" id="membership_period_day" class="w-full" />
        <div class="pr-2">Price</div> $ HKD <input name="membership_price" type="number" id="membership_price" class="w-full" />
        <div><button class='bg-green-500 mt-2 p-2 rounded-md text-white'>Add</button></div>
        
    </form>
```

In my callback in another php file, I have the following:

```
function new_membership($data){
global $wpdb;
$id= 0;
$nonce = $data['test_nonce'];

if ( !wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'new_membership') ) {
    var_dump("nonce rotten!");
    exit; // Get out of here, the nonce is rotten!
}
if (isset ($data['membership_name']) && isset($data['description'])){
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT INTO memberships (membership_name, membership_description, membership_period_day, membership_price) VALUES ( %s, %s, %d, %d)",
        $data['membership_name'], $data['description'], $data['membership_period_day'], $data['membership_price']);
    $wpdb->query($sql);
    $id = $wpdb->insert_id;
}

wp_redirect(get_admin_url()."?page=iMembership-page");
exit();
}
```

But the wp_verify_nonce() keep returning false. I dont know what is the reason and how to fix it.

Edit to reply comment:

to Anton: the value of test_nonce is "07213d197c". On the form I set it like this

```
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'new_membership','test_nonce' ); ?>
```

to Sally CJ: yes, I call it using register_rest_route() in my custom_plugin.php

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {

register_rest_route( 'custom_plugin', 'new_membership',[
    'methods'  => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'new_membership',
]);
}
```

Comment: Hi) what is a value of `$data['test_nonce']` and how did you set it?

Comment: I noticed that your form is being submitted to a custom REST API endpoint, so you should submit the [`wp_rest` nonce](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication) to that endpoint. Otherwise, the current user will always be unauthenticated even if he/she is actually logged-in to your WordPress site. And the endpoint callback should return something and not do things like `exit()` or redirection.. How do you call the `new_membership()` function? Is it directly passed to `register_rest_route()`? Can we see the code?

Comment: Dear Anton and Sally CJ, I have edited above to include my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the wp_verify_nonce() keep returning false

If you were logged-in to your (WordPress) site when you used the form, then the above is normal. Here's why so:

- Your form submits to a custom REST API endpoint (at `/wp-json/ilms_plugin/new_membership`) and the default authentication method used by the REST API is cookie-based, i.e. it checks if a nonce with the action named `wp_rest` is set and that it's valid (not yet expired), and if not (not set or it's invalid/expired), then WordPress sets the current user to `0` which affects all nonce-related functions including but not limited to `wp_verify_nonce()`.
- In simple words, it means functions like `wp_verify_nonce()` will return false because nonces are based on the current user, so if the user is logged-in to your site (when filling in the form), but not the REST API (when the form submission/data is processed), then `wp_verify_nonce()` will return false because the user ID becomes `0` in the REST API.

Check out the REST API handbook for more details about the authentication: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

### How to fix the issue

Just add `wp_nonce_field( 'wp_rest', '_wpnonce', false );` somewhere in your form, e.g. right after the opening `<form>` tag: (Note that I escaped the URL using [`esc_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/))

```php
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( get_rest_url( null, 'ilms_plugin/new_membership' ) ); ?>" ...>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'wp_rest', '_wpnonce', false ); ?>
    ...
```

### Additional Notes

1. Instead of `get_rest_url( null, 'ilms_plugin/new_membership' )`, you could use `rest_url( 'ilms_plugin/new_membership' )` which uses [`rest_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_url/) and is shorter.. :)
2. Instead of using `$wpdb->query()`, I would use [`$wpdb->insert()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/) to insert the data to the database.
3. A REST API endpoint should always set a `permission_callback` and you should also use the `args` argument to define the parameters for the endpoint like the `test_nonce` in your case. Nonetheless, refer to [Adding Custom Endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) in the REST API handbook for further details.

Comment: thank you. that works!